# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com/github/jaiimageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriteParam

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, mirth

I try to do a `Java OCR` project with `Tess4j` using `Maven`.In local,I have no error,but when I create a jar file and call it in `Mirth`,I have the error.When I see Maven Dependencies,I can see `jai_imageio-1.1.jar` and `jai_core-1.1.3.jar`

What is the problem?Thank you for your helps.

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOkNa.png)
[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7254.png)

Comment: did you add jar in mirth via settings>resource>reload resource?.

Comment: Yes,I added them.Actually,I have new problem as _java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO_

Comment: give some screenshot of what you added as resource, and what you are now getting error

Comment: I uploaded new screenshot.Also,I have lots of jar files like tess4j.jar,log4j.jar,jai_imageio-1.1.jar and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not setting proper dependencies in class path.
Refer to below link for fixing this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27390406/3213772

Comment: I remove the jai_imageio-1.1.jar in the resources,I have new error as _java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found_

Answer (score 0):

For using Tess4j try putting the `libtesseract302.dll` in the Project Folder and not in the lib Folder. That is how it worked in project. 
 if it's missing in your project , then download it , and then follow the previous step

Comment: I added `libtesseract302.dll`,`gsdll64.dll`,`liblept168.dll` in the java folders and class folders,but there is still the error.